# Camera Always working in React Native Router Flux Scene

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am looking React Native Router flux and did everything I want, except Camera.
The structure of Router is like this.

```
<Router ...>
  <Scene tabs>
    <Scene />        // Scene1
    <Scene />        // Scene2
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

Scene2 is QR Scanner.
And if app is running, both scene1 and scene2 loaded at same time, and camera always working even though I am at Scene1.
So My devices blows and it seems to explode.

How can I stop camera when I am working on Scene1?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `onEnter/onExit` function together with `Actions.refs.YOUR_CAMERA_SCENE` to start/stop camera like this:

```
   <Router ...>
     <Scene tabs>
       <Scene />        // Scene1
       <Scene key='QR' onEnter={()=>Actions.refs.QR.startCamera()} onExit={()=>Actions.refs.QR.stopCamera()} />        // Scene2
     </Scene>
   </Router>
```

And your `QR` React Component should have `startCamera` and `stopCamera` methods.